# How to find sum of dictionaries in a pandas DataFrame across all rows?

Tags: python, pandas, counter

I have a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'keywords': [{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'c':1, 'd':2}, {'a':5, 'c':21, 'd':4}, {'b':2, 'c':1, 'g':1, 'h':1, 'i':1}]})
```

I want to add all the elements across all rows that would give the result without using `iterrows`:

```
a: 8
b: 6
c: 28
d: 6
g: 1
h: 1
i: 1
```

note: no element occurs twice in a single row in the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), you can `sum` an iterable of `Counter` objects. Since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, you can then feed to [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html).

```
from collections import Counter

counts = sum(map(Counter, df['keywords']), Counter())
res = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counts, orient='index')

print(res)

    0
a   8
b   6
c  28
d   6
g   1
h   1
i   1
```

Comment: figured i could do it with collections but couldn't figure out how to do it. thanks!

Comment: is there a more memory efficient way of doing this? my dataframe is huge and it is taking a long time.

Comment: @panaceanoob, I've updated to `map(Counter, df['keywords'])`. Don't see much improvement possible from here. You already have/chosen a very memory inefficient starting point (holding dictionaries in a dataframe). This isn't recommended. `sum` + `map` is lazy, memory isn't the bottleneck and *not* the reason it's taking a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this compares in terms of optimization with @jpp's answer, but I'll give it a shot.

```
# What we're starting out with
df = pd.DataFrame({'keywords': [{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 5}, {'c':1, 'd':2}, {'a':5, 'c':21, 'd':4}, {'b':2, 'c':1, 'g':1, 'h':1, 'i':1}]})

# Turns the array of dictionaries into a DataFrame
values_df = pd.DataFrame(df["keywords"].values.tolist())

# Sums up the individual keys
sums = {key:values_df[key].sum() for key in values_df.columns}
```